# Как при выборе select активировать блок?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! У меня есть такая задача: при выборе `option`, скажем `<option value="1">Россия</option>`, нужно, чтобы блок `.block` скрывался, а блок `.block-rus` становился доступным. При выборе любого другого `option` - наоборот. При этом в коде, который я представил, изменения производить не могу (например, `option` присвоить `id`), доступно только `value`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это сделать? Благодарю!

```css
.block-rus {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<select data-placeholder="" name="catlist[]" id="category" onchange="onCategoryChange(this)">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="1">Россия</option>
<option value="2">Украина</option>
<option value="3">Белоруссия</option>
</select>
<div class="block">Текст открытый</div>
<div class="block-rus">Скрытый текст</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function onCategoryChange(){
   // какая то ваша функция
}

$("#category").change(function(){
   var v = $(this).val();
   $(".block").toggle(v != 1);
   $(".block-rus").toggle(v == 1);
});
```

```css
.block-rus {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select data-placeholder="" name="catlist[]" id="category" onchange="onCategoryChange(this)">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">Россия</option>
  <option value="2">Украина</option>
  <option value="3">Белоруссия</option>
</select>

<div class="block">Текст открытый</div>
<div class="block-rus">Скрытый текст</div>
```

Comment: @LADYX вам виднее, у вас же написано `<select .. onchagnge="onCategoryChange(this)" ..`